# Hessian matrix and analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, hessian-matrix

I've been trying to solve this problem for a long time, but I don't know exactly how to start:[image]

Translation: M is square dxd, we want to show that f belongs to C^2 in R^d.
After we want to calculate the Hessian matrix and the gradient of the function f(x)

What I've been thinking is to expand M=mij and calculate by hand but I think that would take a long time.(that works well to show it belongs to C^2(R^d)).
Another way I thought it was to use somehow the expansion:
f(a+h)=f(a)++1/2+||h||^2*e(h) where <,>=||.||

Thank you all (sorry for bad format of equations, I'm a beginner)

Comment: I think I'm going to get there if I expand it all, but I really wanted to do it somehow not as ugly as that(if possible)

Comment: What do you know about the differential of a bilinear form ?

Comment: Not a lot actually
What I found about the gradient (expanding it all) was:
grad(f)=b+(M+M^T)x where M^T is the transposition of M.

Comment: If you know that the Taylor expansion is unique, the result is straightforward.